# Creating custom list filter in django

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

I'm extending ListFilter to create a custom ListFilter for Django Admin in Django 1.4, but django is automagically converting my querystring arguments to e=1. Is there any way I can tell Django admin to allow certain parameters; instead of converting them to e=1.

Here's my Custom ListFilter:

```
class DateRangeListFilter(ListFilter):
    """ Custom Date Range Filter using Jquery UI for date-picker """
    title = _('date range')
    template = 'admin/filter_date.html'

    parameters = ['class_after', 'class_before']
    parameter_friendly_names = {parameters[0]: 'Class After', parameters[1]: 'Class Before'}
    parameter_values = {}
    parameter_name = parameters[0]
    used_parameters = {parameters[0]: '', parameters[1]: ''}

    def __init__(self, request, params, model, model_admin):
        super(ListFilter, self).__init__()

        for parameter in self.parameters:
            value = request.GET.get(parameter, None)
            if value:
                self.parameter_values[parameter] = value

        self.lookup_choices = list(self.lookups())

    def has_output(self):
        return len(self.lookup_choices) > 0

    def lookups(self, *args):
        lookup_list = []
        for key in self.parameters:
            lookup_list.append((key, self.parameter_friendly_names[key]))
        return lookup_list

    def expected_parameters(self):
        return self.parameters

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset

    def choices(self, cl):
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            param_name = title
            replace_text = 'gte_icdate' if title == self.parameters[0] else 'lte_icdate'
            value = self.parameter_values[lookup] if self.parameter_values.has_key(lookup) else ''
            yield {
                'param_name': param_name,
                'selected': True if lookup is not None else False,
                'query_string': cl.get_query_string({param_name: replace_text, }, []),
                'value': value,
                'display': title,
                'replace_text': replace_text,
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Django is too magical sometimes. There is almost certainly a right way to do this, and what I'm doing is probably not it. But I modified my **init** function to delete my special parameters from the dictionary; and thus the django admin ignored it.

```
def __init__(self, request, params, model, model_admin):
    super(ListFilter, self).__init__()

    for param_key in self.parameters: 
        if param_key in params.keys():
            self.parameter_values[param_key] = params[param_key]
            del params[param_key]  # This is the anti-magic line
        else:
            self.parameter_values[param_key] = ''

    self.lookup_choices = list(self.lookups())
```

Answer (score -1):

I've seen that happen indeed: it seems you need to leave a "clean" set of parameters to the view.
I've seen pop() is used as a more efficient alternative:

```
def __init__(self, request, params, model, model_admin):
    super(ListFilter, self).__init__()

    for param_key in self.parameters:
        self.parameter_values[param_key] = params.pop(param_key,'')

    self.lookup_choices = list(self.lookups())
```